# Using rsync to keep two servers in sync

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, rsync

I have two AWS EC2 instances that I'm trying to implement a two way sync. So if a file or folder on server1 is created or updated it should sync that file/folder to server2. If it's a new folder it should be created on the server. The problem I'm having is I can't get rsync to create the folders on the 'local' server. 
For example, server 1: /rootdir/1/2/3/4, where directories 3 and 4 do not exist on server2. When I run rsync on server2 I want those new directories to be created.

Here is the code I'm trying to use, running from Server2:
$sudo rsync -avzP  -e "ssh -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/Key.pem" ec2-user@IPADDRESS OF SERVER1:/rootdir/1/2/ /rootdir/1/2

I'm not getting an error but the directories aren't being copied.

I also tried -r but it made no difference.

Comment: Is the rsync program producing any output? You're running it with `-v` so it should output some information on what it's doing.

Comment: The only output is this:  
receiving incremental file list

sent 19 bytes  received 219 bytes  476.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. The servers were configured with a non-standard port and I needed to tell rsync which port to use.